# Google Sheets App Script Add Value Cell Based on Date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following sample sheet which uses the following formulas that somewhat work.  I say somewhat because often opening the sheet there are errors with the filter formulas after sorting filtering the tabs or sometimes when new rows are added.  The values being set are not going to change once set initially so I'm looking for some help getting me started with an app script that will set the values on open if the value in the respective cells are blank.

I'd like to use app script one because of the said errors and also interested in learning it a bit.  I've done a bit of js work in other platforms and confident I can dial this in with help with one or of the following

Transaction Tab

```
    FILTER(text(B2:B,"MMMM"),Not(ISBLANK(B2:B)))
    FILTER(text(B2:B,"YYYY"),Not(ISBLANK(B2:B)))
    filter(if(E2:E < 0,"debit","credit"),not(ISBLANK(E2:E)))
    filter(VLOOKUP(D2:D,Lists!A:B,2,false),not(ISBLANK(B2:B)))
```

BalanceHistory

```
   FILTER(text(B2:B,"MMMM"),Not(ISBLANK(B2:B)))
   FILTER(text(B2:B,"YYYY"),Not(ISBLANK(B2:B)))
   ARRAYFORMULA({"Date/Time"; B2:B+C2:C})
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17SId7mIzO3hVOC36Nq40O0bjPS5YfGOX4wsMU1NlbCU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can refer to this sample code:

```
function onOpen() {
  updateTransactionsSheet();
  updateBalanceHistorySheet();
}

function updateTransactionsSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var transactionSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Transactions");
  var transactionData = transactionSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var listsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Lists");
  var listsData = listsSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var listsMap = {};
  for (var i = 1; i<listsData.length; i++) {
    var category = listsData[i][0];
    var group = listsData[i][1];
    if (!(category in listsMap)) {
      // Add category in the dictionary/javascript object
      listsMap[category] = group;
    }
  }
  Logger.log("Lists Map: "+JSON.stringify(listsMap));

  // Check each row data in the transaction sheet. Ignore header row
  var transactionResult = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < transactionData.length; i++) {
    var row = transactionData[i];
    var date = row[1]; // Get date value in column B (zero-based)
    var category = row[3] // Get category value in column D (zero-based)
    var amount = row[4] // Get amount value in column E (zero-based)

    var dateObj = new Date(date);
    var month = dateObj.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });
    var year = dateObj.getFullYear().toString();
    var amountStr = amount < 0 ? "Debit" : "Credit";
    
    transactionResult.push([month, year, listsMap[category], amountStr])
  }
  Logger.log(transactionResult)
  // Write result in transaction sheet to column P (index 16 one-based) starting from row 2
  transactionSheet.getRange(2,16,transactionResult.length,transactionResult[0].length).setValues(transactionResult);
}

function updateBalanceHistorySheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var balanceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("BalanceHistory");
  var balanceData = balanceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  // Check each row data in the balance sheet. Ignore header row
  var balanceResult = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < balanceData.length; i++) {
    var row = balanceData[i];
    var date = row[1]; // Get date value in column B (zero-based)
    var time = row[2]; // Get date value in column C (zero-based)
    
    var dateObj = new Date(date);
    dateObj.setHours(time.getHours(),time.getMinutes(),0);
    var dateTimeStr = Utilities.formatDate(dateObj, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss");
    var month = dateObj.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });
    var year = dateObj.getFullYear().toString();

    
    balanceResult.push([month, year, dateTimeStr])
  }
  Logger.log(balanceResult)
  //Write result in balance sheet to column M (index 13 one-based) starting from row 2
  balanceSheet.getRange(2,13,balanceResult.length,balanceResult[0].length).setValues(balanceResult);
}
```

### What it does?

- Create an [onOpen() simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onopene) and call `updateTransactionsSheet()` and `updateBalanceHistorySheet()` to update the values of their respective sheets
- In `updateTransactionsSheet()`. Get the current active srpeadsheet object using [getActiveSpreadsheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivespreadsheet). Get transaction sheet object using [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename). Get all data range object in your transaction sheet using [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) then get the values of your range using [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues). It will return a two-dimensional array of values.
- Loop each row (skip header row with index 0) and get the `date value` and the `amount value` in `column B` and `column E` respectively.
- Create a JavaScript [date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) using your `date value`, use [toLocalString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) to get the month string of your date object. And use [getFullYear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear) to get the year of your date object
- Once you obtained the necessary values in your current row, add the data in  the result array using [array.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). Notice that the value pushed is an array `[month, year, "", amountStr]` this is the current row value to be set for 4 columns (columns P to S).
- Write the value to your sheet. Use [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) to get the range where you want to write your data. Since we want to right it from P2:Q, row start will be 2, column start will be 16, num of rows and num of columns will be based on the size of your result array (which is a two-dimensional array). Use [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- Similar process was done for `updateBalanceHistorySheet()`

### Output:

[image]

### (Update)

- I updated the code to include the `Group` column value in `Transactions` sheet. I just read the values in your `Lists` sheet and create a [JavaScript Object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) with column A (Category) as the `key` and column B (Group) as the `value`. Refer to `listsMap` variable on how it was created.
- Then I used the current row's category in `Transactions` sheet to get its equivalent group value in the JavaScript Object.

Comment: cool thank you.  I'll test it out in the next day or two!

Comment: Sure, just let me know if you encountered some issues. By the way, If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: Ron this is awesome and thank you for going into so much detail for the explanation. One follow up, I'm going to mark it resolved now.  However the was one more formula above I'm hoping you could help me see it app script.

On the transaction tab there is a group column, it uses a filter and vLookup to match the category from transactions tab and returns group from lists tab.

if you could help with that amazing.  Thanks again very much.

filter(VLOOKUP(D2:D,Lists!A:B,2,false),not(ISBLANK(D2:D)))

Comment: I updated the answer to include `Group` column value

Comment: That is amazing, thank you so much.  One general follow up question on app scripts.  I've added a tab called month to the sample which is basically a P&L where the data is either sourced from the transactions tab, actual or a budget tab projected.   Is there a reason not to use app script to look up this data based by month and populate the information as opposed to more cumbersome formulas like the one I pasted in the sample spre

Comment: I just provided an apps script solution since you mentioned you are looking for one because your formula fails sometime. But  based on my personal opinion your transaction and balance tab could be populated using formula that will not fail intermittently. For your month tab you might be able to populate it with formula, but it might be challenging to use arrayformula, you might require to drag your base formula to your succeeding cells. As such cases, you can use apps script to populate your information needed.

Comment: But then again, it really depends on which solution you are comfortable :). For me, its quite easier to use apps script in manipulating the data in the sheet

Comment: Okay great, never really worked with app script so learning a bit there.  I'm going to tinker away at.  thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Quick follow up on this one.  It has been working amazing without issue.  However today I try adding the code exactly as is to different google sheet and started getting the error "TypeError: time.getHours is not a function".  The only difference I can see is the original sheets were from corporate account and now I'm trying to add it to my personal account.  Would there be any setting I'd need to possibly turn on by chance.  I notices AppScript is under tools in my business account but under extension in my personal.  That made me think GCS might enable something natively.

Comment: I suspect that the date that was read in your new sheet file is not a date object, compared to your original sheet file. Compare the number format of your date in your original file and in your new file